# GMail LDAP Authentication?

Tags: php, ldap, gmail

My company has Google Apps for Business so we can manage our coworkers GMail accounts.  Is there anyway to set up GMail to use LDAP for user authentication with PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This Google link](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=106368) really helped me get it set up when I did it for a customer last year. It was frustrating, but I figured it out!

Good luck.